# can you put a tablename in a column? and should you?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I would like to create a highly scalable system for storing "candidates" the problem is each candidate has different "features" and sometimes these have different data types. One idea I'd like to try would involve something like this:

candidates:

```
| id |    cType   |
   1    'fabric'
   2     'belt'
```

candidateFeatures:

```
| candidateId | featureTable | featureId
       1          'city'         1
       1         'colour'        1
       1         'colour'        2
       2          'city'         2
       2          'size'         1
```

city:

```
|id | lat | lng |   name  |
  1    x     x    'London' 
  1    x     x     'Paris'
```

colour:

```
|id |  name  |
 1    'Red'
 2   'Green'
```

size:

```
|id |  value  |
 1     10
 2     12
```

Here you can see that there is one fabric candidate in London with Red and Green features and a belt candidate in Paris with size 10. 
we do this because we get feedback in a universal way and I'm trying to write a scalable machine learning solution that will allow new types of candidates to be added seamlessly, as well as new candidate feature types - as they are discovered and added to the db. A candidate is assumed to be able to have more than one of each feature type.
Ultimately I need to be able to extract the data (probably through a materialised view) so that if I want all 'fabric' candidates I would end up with something like:

```
'id' |  colourIds  |  cityIds  |
  1     [1, 2]         [1]
  4      [3]         [4, 5]
```

but then if one day I find a fabric that doesn't have a colour but instead has a pattern I can easily get a new table for patterns and just add the features to my "candidateFeatures" table:

```
'id' |  colourIds  |  cityIds  | patternIds
  1     [1, 2]         [1]        null
  4      [3]         [4, 5]       null
  14      null         [6]        [1]
```

This format is suitable for the front end, and the format of "candidateFeatures" is very useful for the backend. we can use it to easily scale without modifying existing tables and for scalable data analysis. Specifically when looking for correlations between user responses to candidates and presence of categorical features - or values of continuous features.

To me this seems like a really clever idea that hasn't got proper support in sql… which makes me think it's probably a really dumb idea in disguise. I think it's possible to do this using EXEC, but that does have some risks. Does anyone know of a smarter way to achieve the same result? or actually how to achieve this? 
Since execution time isn't such a big concern I can always run it through a third party program e.g. in python and put the results into new tables. But ideally I'd use a bunch of materialised views and have them update periodically because that feels like it would scale better with more data.

Comment: This is a well know problem with "dynamic attributes". Your first model is known as the (anti) pattern Entity Attribute Value. Nowadays I would just create table `candidate` with all common attributes as proper columns, and a `JSONB` column that stores key/value pairs to store the candidate specific attributes

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

It is neither a good idea nor an awful idea.  It is simply not how SQL works.  The problem is that queries have a well-defined set of tables and column references.  This is quite important for optimizing the query -- a step that generally happens before the query is run.

Queries are *not* merely strings that permit dynamic substitution when they are processing data.

There are ways to address the data modeling:

- Have separate tables for the features and association tables to match them back to the original data.
- Use an entity-attribute-value model, which basically stored key-value pairs.
- Use a flexible storage mechanism, such as JSON or arrays.

In addition, Postgres supports something called inheritance, which might be useful for representing this type data.